# Ramda - combine duplicates of objects in array with same key value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I have an array of objects, where I want to combine if they have the same name, and add their feederTeams into an array.

The array looks like this:

```
const TEAMS = [{
    name: 'Liverpool',
    id: '1',
    feederTeam: 'Tranmere'
}, {
    name: 'Liverpool',
    id: '2',
    feederTeam: 'Stockport'
}, {
    name: 'Man Utd',
    feederTeam: 'Bla',
    id: '3',
}, {
    name: 'Liverpool',
    id: '6',
    feederTeam: 'Oldham'
}]
```

and I want to transform it into this using Ramda:

```
[{
    name: 'Liverpool',
    feederTeam: ['Tranmere', 'Stockport', 'Oldham']
}, {
    name: 'Man Utd',
    feederTeam: ['Bla'],
}]
```

I have tried many approaches with no luck. Here is my latest attempt.

```
R.forEach((team => R.filter(R.propEq('name', team.name), TEAMS)), TEAMS);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to group several elements together use R.groupBy. Then get an array from the object of groups with R.values, and map each group to the required form:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, values, map, applySpec, nth } = R

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('name')), // group object by the name property
  values, // get an array of groups
  map(applySpec({ // map each group to an object
    name: pipe(nth(0), prop('name')), // take the name from the 1st object in the group
    feederTeam: map(prop('feederTeam')), // collect all feedTeam props to an array
  })),
)

const teams = [{"name":"Liverpool","id":"1","feederTeam":"Tranmere"},{"name":"Liverpool","id":"2","feederTeam":"Stockport"},{"name":"Man Utd","feederTeam":"Bla","id":"3"},{"name":"Liverpool","id":"6","feederTeam":"Oldham"}]

const result = fn(teams)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

A slight variation would be to map the object of groups with R.mapObjIndexed. In this case the `name` the key (is the 2nd param supplied to R.applySpec). After mapping the groups to objects, convert the result to an array with R.values:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, values, mapObjIndexed, applySpec, map, nthArg } = R

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('name')), // group object by the name property
  mapObjIndexed(applySpec({ // map each group to an object
    name: nthArg(1), // take the name from key (2nd arg)
    feederTeam: map(prop('feederTeam')), // collect all feedTeam props to an array
  })),
  values, // convert to an array of objects
)

const teams = [{"name":"Liverpool","id":"1","feederTeam":"Tranmere"},{"name":"Liverpool","id":"2","feederTeam":"Stockport"},{"name":"Man Utd","feederTeam":"Bla","id":"3"},{"name":"Liverpool","id":"6","feederTeam":"Oldham"}]

const result = fn(teams)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```